# How to use the -fteInMXComponents compiler option with flexmojos

Tags: flex4, flexmojos

When compiling a Flex 4 app with flexmojos, how do I specify the -fteInMXComponents (use Flash text engine in MX components) option? Or can I not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution...

Firstly, you can't specify that option, but you can set up your code to do the same thing. All you have to do is take a copy of the file MXFTEText.css from the SDK and put it in your project, then include it as a style sheet:

```
<fx:Style 
    source="MXFTEText.css"/>
```

This will achieve exactly the same thing as -fteInMXComponents.